# After Catalina upgrade and server to 5.9, AFP ACL access locked, SMB access ok

Tags: network, permission, server.app, file-sharing, afp

After upgrading a file sharing server to macOS 10.15.3 and Server 5.9, we can mount our shared volumes via AFP but can not open them because of permissions.

We can access them through SMB but are then having a very old issue (documented somewhere else in this forum I think) where ACL's have to be propagated again up to 10 times a day.

Remote access to the shares with SMB is also complicated due to classic 445 port issues that we don't have with AFP (port 549).

What I have tried:

- Propagated permissions via "view info" screen
- Propagated permissions with TinkerTool
- Removed permissions with TinkerTool
- Again propagated permissions with TinkerTool
- Removed, restarted then reinstated all the shares/users-groups in File Sharing/prefs panel.
- Restarted server several times

To no avail, problem is still there. What other things should I try?

Comment: Just tested it in virtual lab (server 10.15.3 (AFP), client 10.11.6) & I had no problem at all to add complex ACLs and got proper access permissions for the different users and groups I created. Please add some details (like `ls -le ...` listings) for the shared files & folders.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved after investigating the sharing, groups & users and permissions setup with a remote desktop app.

---

All shared folders resided on an external drive which was an old system drive. Remnants could be found like a /bin, /sbin, /usr the usual symlink suspects and some other files and folders (all invisible). The groups & users were properly set up. Permissions for the disk and file & folders were set (but rather unclear to me).

The basic problem/bug could't be found, because time was short (and I was lazy).

---

My proposal was: building everything from scratch

1. Add an admin to each sharing group (if not done already)
2. Disable sharing for the drive (or the shared folders)
3. Copy all shared folders to a second external drive, remove all ACLs and use `(sudo) chown ... -R ...` to reset all major folders and their content to adminuser:admin
4. Format the external drive to JHFS+
5. Create as adminuser a main folder Shared on the drive:

   ```
   mkdir /Volumes/ExternalDrive/Shared
   ls -ale /Volumes/ExternalDrive/Shared
   total 0
   drwxr-xr-x   2 adminuser  admin   68 Feb 11 18:55 .
   drwxrwxr-x  10 root       admin  408 Feb 11 18:55 ..
   ```
6. Copy all major subfolders back to /Volumes/ExternalDrive/Shared

   Example/Result:

   ```
   ls -ale /Volumes/ExternalDrive/Shared    
   total 0
   drwxr-xr-x   4 adminuser  admin  136 Feb 11 19:10 .
   drwxrwxr-x  10 root       admin  408 Feb 11 18:55 ..
   drwxr-xr-x   2 adminuser  admin   68 Feb 11 19:10 develop
   drwxr-xr-x   2 adminuser  admin   68 Feb 11 19:10 finance
   ```
7. Apply chmod 750 to the main subfolders:

   ```
   chmod 750 /Volumes/ExternalDrive/Shared/develop
   chmod 750 /Volumes/ExternalDrive/Shared/finance
   ```
8. Apply group ACLs (I named the dev group develop and the fin group finance - like the folders)

   Examples (the example ACL allows **full** access to all sub-subfolders - every user of the respective group can really do anything, so be aware/fine tune it):

   ```
   chmod -R +a "group:develop allow readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,list,search,add_file,add_subdirectory,delete_child,file_inherit,directory_inherit" /Volumes/ExternalDrive/Shared/develop
   chmod -R +a "group:finance allow readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,list,search,add_file,add_subdirectory,delete_child,file_inherit,directory_inherit" /Volumes/ExternalDrive/Shared/finance
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   ls -ale /Volumes/ExternalDrive/Shared
   total 0
   drwxr-xr-x   4 adminuser  admin  136 Feb 11 19:10 .
   drwxrwxr-x  10 root       admin  408 Feb 11 18:55 ..
   drwxr-x---+  2 adminuser  admin   68 Feb 11 19:10 develop
    0: group:develop allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
   drwxr-x---+  2 adminuser  admin   68 Feb 11 19:10 finance
    0: group:finance allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
   ```
9. Enable (AFP) sharing for the *Shared* folder **or** share each main subfolder (i.e. develop, finance etc.)

   In the first case all users can access the *Shared* but have no or restricted access to subfolders. Example (member of the *develop* group opens the share - other groups' members have no access at all, except if a user is member of several groups and *develop* is one of it)

   [image: Shared/develop]

   In the second case (e.g. sharing *develop* and logging in as member of the *develop* group)

   [image: develop]
10. If you need to have personalized sub-subfolders (access for one user of the group only), you have to stop the "global" group ACL and add a new user ACL.

---

AFP-Sharing worked again afterwards.

Comment: @MarkD Please ask a new question. Your problem is unrelated to the original question. It's really too difficult to get the proper formatting of a command and its output when it is posted as comment